# Append Intent with String or current time stamp

Tags: android, string, android-intent, append, intentservice

I want to append resultIntent with a string or a current timestamp.
Tell me If anybody knows.

Comment: You can add "extras" to an `Intent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for help guyz.

Adding putExtra haven't solved my problem...

But adding setAction solved it..

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you can add key-value pairs to Intents - just add an "extra" with the data you want.